# How to decouple System.getenv from static field in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've a legacy code as below

```
@Service
public class CLConf {
    static final String CI_ENV = System.getenv("ENV").toUpperCase(); <-- NPE when doing junits
    // other config variables
}
```

This works when we run the code normally in application. but I've issues creating test cases that use class `CLConf` something like below.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CLConf.class) <<----------- ISSUE while loading bcz env is not set yet
public class CLServiceTest {
    //test cases
}
```

currently it throws NPE because of `.toUpperCase()`

Since CI_ENV is directly being set from `System.getenv`, while writing class for Junits, this class is loaded using `@ContextConfiguration`. And I'm not sure where to set `env` variables for Test cases so that it doesn't break while loading `CLConf`.

How do I configure/do setup for test cases OR how do i decouple `System.getenv` so that I can supply my own config while testing?

Note: there are many System.getenv in class CLConf, above is just minified class.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide test configurations using the `locations` or `value` attribute of the [`TestPropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) annotation, directly defining your test properties in a file or selectly override properties like stated in the documentation:

> @TestPropertySource is a class-level annotation that is used to
> configure the locations() of properties files and inlined properties()
> to be added to the Environment's set of PropertySources for an
> ApplicationContext for integration tests.
> Test property sources have higher precedence than those loaded from
> the operating system's environment or Java system properties as well
> as property sources added by the application declaratively via
> @PropertySource or programmatically (e.g., via an
> ApplicationContextInitializer or some other means). Thus, test
> property sources can be used to selectively override properties
> defined in system and application property sources

Comment: I tried this did not work somehow